# RadComboBox wrong selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, radcombobox

I face the following problem when i use `RadComboBox` :

```
    ddl_contactList.Items.Clear();
    ddl_contactList.DataSource = ContactList.GetContactListsByDep(year, main_code);
    ddl_contactList.DataTextField = "list_desc";
    ddl_contactList.DataValueField = "list_code";
    ddl_contactList.DataBind();
    ddl_contactList.Items.Insert(0, new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem("NewList", "-1"));
    ddl_contactList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

---

```
  <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl_contactList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="False"
            CollapseDelay="0" Culture="ar-EG" ExpandDelay="0" Filter="StartsWith" ItemsPerRequest="10"
            MarkFirstMatch="true" Skin="Outlook" EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True" EmptyMessage="-List name-"
            ShowMoreResultsBox="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddl_contactList_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems ="true">
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

---

always the number of items in the combo box is `1` !!! although the datasource contains many items so when i try to get the selected value for any item in any time, i always get `-1` !!

How to get the correct `selectedvalue` ?

Comment: I think you should add an item to collection before using it as DataSource...

Answer (score 1):

Add the `NewList` item before databinding and add the following attribute to RadComboBox.

**Setting AppendDataBoundItems to True preserves the items that are already present in RadComboBox. This lets you bind RadComboBox to multiple data sources or use both unbound and bound modes.**

Then add the datasource to the control.

```
ddl_contactList.Items.Clear();
ddl_contactList.Items.Insert(0, new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem("NewList", "-1"));
ddl_contactList.SelectedIndex = 0;


ddl_contactList.DataSource = ContactList.GetContactListsByDep(year, main_code);
ddl_contactList.DataTextField = "list_desc";
ddl_contactList.DataValueField = "list_code";
ddl_contactList.DataBind();
```

Comment: when i call it in the (!page.IsPostBack) i get the following client error:
`There is no assigned datasource,unable to complete callback request`

Comment: have u set AppendDataBoundItems= true

Comment: You can do following method also,protected void RadComboBox1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var combo = (RadComboBox)sender; 
    combo.Items.Insert(0, new RadComboBoxItem("Select a country", string.Empty)); 
}

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-insert-default-item-when-databinding.html

Answer (score 1):

How about adding them individually instead of binding.

```
var items = ContactList.GetContactListsByDep(year, main_code); 

foreach(var item in items)
{
   ddl_contactList.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(item.list_desc, item.list_code));
}

ddl_contactList.Items.Insert(0, new RadComboBoxItem("NewList", "-1")); 
ddl_contactList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I did that , and it works but when there are many items the `comcbo box` becomes so heavy onloading !!

Comment: You might want to consider using  OnItemsRequested. It loads combobox items via ajax when user starts typing inside the combobox. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx